# Google app script regex to split first and last names

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, split

I'm using a google app script to pull data from an email to the a sheet. Part of the body of the email comes in with this line "Name*: first last".

I've got this line that pulls out the name, but I'd like to actually pull out "first" and "last" names separately. I'm thinking you can do that somehow with regex.

```
var name = messages[j].getPlainBody().split("Name*: ")[1].split("\n")[0];
```

I'm trying to do this with:

```
var fName = messages[j].getPlainBody().split("Name*: ")[1].str.split(/\s(.+)/)[0];
var lName = messages[j].getPlainBody().split("Name*: HOW TO SKIP FIRST NAME ")[1].split("\n")[0];
```

Having some difficulty. Little help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the split function, you get an array with the splitted elements in each position of the array. Use something like this:

```
var name = messages[j].getPlainBody().split("Name*: ")[1].str.split(/\s(.+)/);
var fName = name[0];
var lName = name[1];
```